# Does Chrome save bookmarks to the cloud?

Tags: google-chrome

I know Chrome syncs your bookmarks across computers by having you connect a Google account with the browser, but does it save them? If each of my two computers were obliterated by meteors, and I bought a new one and logged in, would I still have all my bookmarks?

I know it sounds like a given assuming they're synced, but I just want to hear it from someone who knows for certain that they can't be lost.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. You can see what's currently in the cloud on [this page](https://www.google.com/settings/chrome/sync).

Comment: I guess that's a security measure, you have to sign in again to confirm that it's you. (in case you're using the "remember me" feature and someone else has access to your computer)

Comment: (I made a mistake, was using multiple accounts, wasn't signed in to Gmail under the same account as I was signed in to chrome with.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. And to access these bookmarks you have to install chrome.

Comment: If you read the answer given and accepted you'd know this isn't the case. It is a good idea to read existing answers before adding your own, especially if the question is nearly 7 years old and the existing answers have been accepted as correct.